# Check if third-party cookies are set

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

Assuming that the user visits a domain A, how can I check that there is third-party cookies set within an iframe from domain B loaded unter the domain A or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can't check or read any cookie from different domain, your browser will not allow that, except if:

- The Domain A has some JavaScript loaded from Domain B
- The JavaScript set some cookie
- Then the browser allow to send that cookie to Domain B when loaded in Iframe inside Domain A